# Software that uses Cardano's method to solve a cubic?

Tags: polynomials, math-software, cubics

I am writing an essay for my school. I am think of testing the speed of the Cardano's formula for different types of cubic polynomial. Is there any software or calculator that uses the Cardano's formula to solve a cubic?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: to do such timing tests you usually need to write the code yourself, or to copy it from someone else (with his permission). How are you going to time the speed of the software otherwise? Certainly not with a wrist watch ;-)

Comment: Mathematica definitely will work. You could also just explicitly write out cardano's formula in Python if you don't have or don't want to buy a Mathematica license.

Comment: @ZachStone That is really helpful :). But can they test the speed of the method?

Comment: Yup. Both languages have timers.